# Как настроить клавиатуру в Debian?

Tags: debian, клавиатура

Установил Debian и получил кривую программную раскладку клавиатуры. А именно: при нажатии клавиши "| \ / " у меня вместо этих символов вводится "~" и "#". Менял параметр "Keyboard layout", ничего не помогает. Как привести программную раскладку клавиатуры в соответствие с физической раскладкой? Клавиатура - Defender XM500

Comment: А что показывает `setxkbmap -print` ?

Comment: `xkb_keymap { xkb_keycodes { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" }; xkb_types { include "complete" }; xkb_compact { include "complete" }; xkb_symbols { include "pc+gb+inet(evdev)" }; xkb_geometry { include "pc(pc104)" }; };`

Comment: Надо поменять британскую раскладку (`gb`) на американскую (`us`).